# Can branches visually see the changes made to the html file?

Tags: git, github, branch

So I made a Github hosted site. When making a webpage you tend to want to see the changes visually when you change something and I find it very annoying to keep adding, committing, and pushing every time I make a small change. Can I make a branch, make changes there, and still see the changes visually or do I need to merge to master branch before changes are displayed on the site? If branching doesn't work, how do you developers out there deal with this issue?

Comment: Working on a branch doesn't eliminate adding, committing and pushing.

Answer (score 0):

The files on-disk will be the same as whatever branch you are currently on. So basically if you make a branch and make changes, that's what's currently on-disk, so you can see the changes in real-time. "Master" branch doesn't mean "only one visible to the file system", it's just a moniker for something that is intended to be the final production/working branch.

Comment: So say if I made a branch on the repository and I make a bunch of changes to it and am currently working on that branch. Would the www.username.github.io/folder/index.html show the contents of the branch or would it show the master branch?